# Conditional count on the basis of an array within an array of subdocuments in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of chats

```
    {
      "_id": "60b886babeeb7301c49cd114",
      "participants": [
        "6096c0067a9acc2164f4a14e",
        "6096bfea7a9acc2164f4a14c"
      ],
      "access": [
        "6096c0067a9acc2164f4a14e",
        "6096bfea7a9acc2164f4a14c"
      ],
      "messages": [
        {
          "access": [
            "6096c0067a9acc2164f4a14e"
          ],
          "seen": [
            "6096bfea7a9acc2164f4a14c"
          ],
        "message": "This is message 5",
        "from": "6096bfea7a9acc2164f4a14c",
          "_id": "60b88764da05c21e5483410b",
        },
        
      ],
    },...
```

i want to get the chats back where the requesting user is present in the chat's access list but i also need to send along some additional information, such as the last message and total unseen messages for a chat. Getting a total of unseen messages for each chat is causing me trouble. In my head the flow should be something like this.

1. Traverse/Unwind the messages array.
2. Check for each message if the user is in `access` list and not in `seen` list increment come count.
3. Add this count to each chat object.

I have tried to find a purely mongodb solution with aggregation pipeline, positional projects but just couldn't find any way of achieving above mentioned steps.

How i am doing it now is by traversing the cursor in JavaScript after filtering the chats.

```
      let messages = chat.messages;      
      let unseenMessages = 0;
      messages.forEach(msg => {
        if (
          msg.access.includes(req.session.userId) &&
          !msg.seen.includes(req.session.userId)
        ) {
          unseenMessages += 1;
          console.log('unseen message', msg.message);
        }
      });
```

Is there a way to achieve this without getting JavaScript involved? and if you like suggest any changes in the schema, i have a feeling my schema design is not very optimal.

Comment: What is the purpose of "access" on chats? Are you restricting messages in a chat from other users?

Comment: The access list in a chat restricts access to the whole chat. Each message aslo has an access list for more granular control.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but since you asked for Schema design suggestion based on your current model -

I dont see the significance in the data model for granular control on messages. I would recommend you to have 3 schema's for your chat application.

1. **Chat** - This will have list of users that have access to chat/group

   {
   "users": {Str(User._id: Object(User)}, // Map as this reduces search complexity
   "messages": Array(message)
   }
2. **User** - Many-to-many relation with chats. Will also store the "last read message id index" used to update "message_seen_by" by index from chat.messages.seen_by.append(user._id)

   {
   chat : { Str(Chat) : Object(Str),
   lastMessageReadIndex: Number
   }
3. **Message** - One-to-many relation with chat. Will store message as well as seen by list of users.

   {
   chat: Obj(chat),
   txt: string,
   seen_by : Array[User]
   }

This is a dummy model, you can update the schema further based on your preferences. Hope this approach helps.

Comment: I want more granular control on messages for a few reasons.
1. If one party deletes a message we don't want it to be removed from the database and in consequence from all other parties.
2. If a party deletes a chat and then renters it, they shouldn't be able to access previous messages but the other parties should still be able to access them.

Comment: In your case, you can have the users from chat also available as visible messages